# Laravel relationship : one foreignKey for several localKey relationship

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys, relationship, has-many

I have to develop an api with Laravel and i'm stuck with this problem:
I need to get all matchs and for each match i need to get the users who belongs to this match (there is 2 users per match)

I've search answer for this problem and i found this https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships but it didn't worked for me.

So far, i have this :

```
class Match extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'matchs';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function playerOne() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'playerOne_id');
    }

    public function playerTwo() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'playerTwo_id');
    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public function index()
{
    $matchs = Match::with('playerOne', 'playerTwo')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return $matchs; 
    //return new MatchsCollection($matchs);
}
```

and my database look like this :
(Matchs table)

```
id    | playerOne_id   | playertwo_id | winner_id | status 
------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1              | 3            | 0         | PENDING
2     | 2              | 1            | 0         | PENDING
3     | 3              | 2            | 0         | PENDING
```

and users table :

```
id    | name      | email           
-----------------------------------
1     | John      | John@email.com 
2     | Mark      | Mark@email.com
3     | Harry     | Harry@email.com
```

and when i call my api i get this result:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    playerOne_id: 1,
    playerTwo_id: 3,
    winner_id: 0,
    status: "PENDING",
    created_at: "2019-01-10 00:00:00",
    updated_at: null,
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        email: "John@email.com",
        email_verified_at: null,
        created_at: "2019-01-11 10:38:26",
        updated_at: "2019-01-11 10:38:26"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    playerOne_id: 2,
    playerTwo_id: 1,
    winner_id: 0,
    status: "PENDING",
    created_at: "2019-01-11 08:26:28",
    updated_at: "2019-01-11 08:26:28",
    users: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Mark",
        email: "Mark@email.com",
        email_verified_at: null,
        created_at: "2019-01-11 10:40:13",
        updated_at: "2019-01-11 10:40:13"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    playerOne_id: 3,
    playerTwo_id: 2,
    winner_id: 0,
    status: "PENDING",
    created_at: "2019-01-11 08:45:22",
    updated_at: "2019-01-11 08:45:22",
    users: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "harry",
        email: "harry@email.com",
        email_verified_at: null,
        created_at: "2019-01-11 10:40:13",
        updated_at: "2019-01-11 10:40:13"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i wan't to get is this result (i just show you the first match)

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    playerOne_id: 1,
    playerTwo_id: 3,
    winner_id: 0,
    status: "PENDING",
    created_at: "2019-01-10 00:00:00",
    updated_at: null,
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        email: "John@email.com",
        email_verified_at: null,
        created_at: "2019-01-11 10:38:26",
        updated_at: "2019-01-11 10:38:26"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Harry",
        email: "Harry@email.com",
        email_verified_at: null,
        created_at: "2019-01-11 10:38:26",
        updated_at: "2019-01-11 10:38:26"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

is this possible in Laravel ? thanks :)

Comment: how do you call your api exactly? how do you query?

Comment: why dont you add two relations in your match `Model` i.e.

`public function playerOne() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\User::class, 'id', 'playerOne_id');
}`

`public function playerTwo() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\User::class, 'id', 'playerTwo_id');
}`

and fetch them using eager load.

Comment: @AliMrj  $matchs = Match::with('users')->get();

Comment: @RossWilson $matchs = Match::with('users')->get();

Comment: @FarrukhAyyaz how do i query/fetch this in my controller ?

Comment: `Match::with('playerOne', 'playerTwo')->get();`

Comment: @RossWilson it does work but i have playerOne in an array and playerTwo in anoter array is it possible to have both on the same array (array users for exemple)

Comment: Can you add your controller code to your question?

Comment: @RossWilson My controller : i'm supposed to pass what i get to my resource i know but it didn't solve      
`public function index()
    {

        $matchs = Match::with('playerOne','playerTwo')->orderBy('created_at','asc')->get();
        return $matchs;
        //return new MatchsCollection($matchs);
    }`

Comment: Would changing the relationship between `Match` and `User` to be a `belongsToMany` be possible? i.e. removing the `playerOne_id ` and `playertwo_id` and having a pivot table instead?

Comment: @RossWilson yes it's possible but i have no idea of how does it works? (and should i update my model in my question ? i'm new asking in stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to return all the players as part of the `user` array you could either change the relation between `Match` and `User` to be a [belongsToMany (many-to-many)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) or simply manipulate the match data before returning it from the controller.

Changing it to a `BelongsToMany` would be my recommendation since it semantically makes more sense, however, I understand that (depending on how much work you've done so far) it may not be practical.

You would need to:

1. rename your `matchs` table to be `matches` (this will also mean you can remove
   `protected $table = 'matchs';` from your `Match` model class ).
2. Create a table called `match_user`. If your project is using migrations then you can run:
   `php artisan make:migration create_match_user_table --create=match_user`
   In that migration you would need to change the contents of the `up()` method to be:

   ```
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('match_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->integer('match_id')->unsigned();
           $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
           $table->timestamps();

           $table->primary(['match_id', 'user_id']);
       });
   }
   ```
3. Run `php artisan migrate`
4. In your `Match` model change the `users()` relationship to be:

   ```
   public function users()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
   }
   ```
5. If the data you have in your tables is dummy data you can skip this step. Otherwise, you'll need to move the `playerOne_id` and `playertwo_id` information to the new pivot table. You could do that will the following:

   ```
   Match::all()->each(function ($match) {
       $match->users()->attach([$match->playerOne_id, $match->playertwo_id]);
   });
   ```

   It doesn't really matter where you run this as it only has to be run once so after you've run it you can delete it. I would usually run this in a route or in tinker.
6. Then comes the clean up. Again, if the data you have is just dummy data, then I would just remove the `playerOne_id` and `playertwo_id` the original migration, otherwise create a new migration that removes those field [Dropping columns docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#dropping-columns)

---

Once the above has been done you would just need to do the following in your controller to get the results:

```
$matches = Match::with('users')->latest()->get();
```